# Processing data in DataTable - how to find minimum and maximum for each column?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable object that is filled with numeric data from my database. I have to handle all possible numeric-like data types (int32, int64, float, even datetime, but that last is not necessary).

I have to normalize all data in columns, each column separately, so I need to find maximum and minimum values for each column to calculate normalization coefficient.

Do I have to iterate "manually" through all rows to find these max and min values?

Some background:

I don't want to do this in SQL, because its kind of scientific application, where user works in SQL language and writes very complicated SQL queries. I don't want to force user to write even more complicated queries to get normalized data or get min/max values

Colums are fully dynamic, they depend on SQL query written by user.

Comment: Can you take the column values as an IEnumerable???

Comment: are all integer datatype ?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know how to use IEnumerable :(

Comment: @Arshad No. I have to handle all possible numeric data types, not only integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to iterate "manually" through all rows to find these max and
>   min values?

Define *manually*. Yes, you have to calculate the `Min` and `Max` values by enumerating all `DataRows`. But that can be done either with the old `DataTable.Compute` method or with

[**Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx):

```
int minVal = table.AsEnumerable().Min(r => r.Field<int>("ColName"));
int maxVal = table.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("ColName"));
```

[`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx):

```
int maxVal = (int)table.Compute("Max(ColName)", "");
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell something about speed and memory usage on these 2 methods, or I have to check that myself?

Comment: Linq is more powerful in terms of readability,expandability and maintainability. Both are similar in terms of speed and memory usage(even the `DataRow.Field` extension method needs to box/unbox the values under the hood even though  it seems to be strongly typed).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var min = myTable.AsEnumerable().Min(x => (int)x["column"]);
var max = myTable.AsEnumerable().Max(x => (int)x["column"]);
```

You'll need to make sure you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, which is not added to new projects by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Compute("min(columnname)", string.Empty));
Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Compute("max(columnname)", string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `DataTable.Select()` as :

```
DataRow [] dr = dataTable.Select("ID= MAX(ID)");  

 if(dr !=null)
    {
     // Console.WriteLine(dr[0]["ID"]);
        int maxVal=Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]["ID"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me

```
int  max = Convert.ToInt32(datatable_name.AsEnumerable()
                        .Max(row => row["column_Name"]));
```